# conflicting trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

i need help with my oracle sql code i got an error that i shouldn't get on this insert

```
UPDATE PRENOTAZIONI SET STATO='ACCETTATO' WHERE ID_PRENOTA='P00000011'


Errore con inizio alla riga : 16 nel comando -
Report error -
ORA-20007: Imposssibile accettare prenotazione: limite posti auto superato
ORA-06512: at "CARPOOLING_DBA.TR_MAX_NUM_OSPITI", line 16
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CARPOOLING_DBA.TR_MAX_NUM_OSPITI'
ORA-06512: at "CARPOOLING_DBA.SETTO_PAGA", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CARPOOLING_DBA.SETTO_PAGA'



UPDATE PRENOTAZIONI SET STATO='ACCETTATO' WHERE ID_PRENOTA='P00000011';
```

the first of the two triggers clashing

```
   create or replace TRIGGER TR_MAX_NUM_OSPITI
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PRENOTAZIONI
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE 
  ERRORE EXCEPTION;
  POSTI_DISP NUMBER (1):=0;
  BEGIN
  --QUERY
  SELECT V.POSTI_DISPONIBILI INTO POSTI_DISP
  FROM VIAGGI V
  WHERE V.ID_VIAGGIO=:NEW.VIAGGIO;
  IF(:NEW.N_OSPITI+1<=POSTI_DISP)
  THEN NULL;
  ELSE RAISE ERRORE;
  END IF;
  exception
  WHEN ERRORE THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20007,'Imposssibile accettare prenotazione: limite posti auto superato');
  END;
```

the second of the two triggers clashing

```
create or replace TRIGGER SETTO_PAGA
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OF STATO ON PRENOTAZIONI
BEGIN
UPDATE PRENOTAZIONI
SET PAGATO='Y'
WHERE PAGATO='N' AND STATO='ACCETTATO';
END;
```

if needed i can add the table PRENOTAZIONI and other triggers too... i just cant find the cause of the error.... the insert should go fine i checked all the values and the error i get just dont make any sense.. at least for me..

Comment: I am curious if you still have this problem if you wrap your TR_MAX_NUM_OSPITI code in a conditional like `IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() <= 1`. I might be misunderstanding your code, but I'm guessing you're not expecting the first trigger to be called again when the second trigger does its update on the table. You might want to look at the `nested triggers` and `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` settings on your database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-nested-triggers

Comment: Okay, me linking Microsoft documentation and syntax was dumb when you clearly have ORA errors (but this post was originally tagged with SQL Server). My point still stands in that I'm not sure you're accounting for recursive triggers.

Comment: thank you, after reading your answer i understood the problem... the trigger fired each other in loop when i tried to update STATO so i just added   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF STATO ON PRENOTAZIONI
adding "OF STATO" i dont get the error :D

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see anything "clashing" here. The cause of the error is

```
IF(:NEW.N_OSPITI+1<=POSTI_DISP)
THEN NULL;
ELSE RAISE ERRORE;
END IF;
```

When `ERRORE` is raised the exception block at the end of `TR_MAX_NUM_OSPITI` is invoked:

```
exception
  WHEN ERRORE THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20007,'Imposssibile accettare prenotazione: limite posti auto superato');
```

This throws the user exception -20007, which is the cause of the ORA-20007 at the beginning of the list of messages you included in your question. So there errors are caused because because `:NEW.N_OSPITI+1` is greater than `POSTI_DISP` in `TR_MAX_NUM_OSPITI`.

Best of luck.

Comment: the problem was that the firing condiction was not met